# Does a question that address universal/global phenomenon need a regional tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I'm revisiting my questions to add regional tag, and stumbled on this question:

[Why the closer the relationship is, the worse conflict we experience?](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/499/why-the-closer-the-relationship-is-the-worse-conflict-we-experience)

I don't know if I should add a regional tag for this, because I think this is a phenomenon that everyone in Asia, Europe, America, Africa, Australia experience.

However, I know that not all question is like this, so I'm not advocating against regional tag, of course.

**Is this question (like this) fine without regional tag?**
If **not** (that makes it too broad), **how can I improve it** - without losing the impression that this happens universally?

Or is this even **off-topic** for this site? (For another question, if yes)

Comment: "I think this is a phenomenon that everyone in Asia, Europe, America, Africa, Australia experience." True. But people in each of those places deal with this issue in different ways.

Comment: But it's not asking about *how* to handle it, but rather *why*?

Comment: the *why* also depends on where you are. Unlike the hard sciences, there are very few universal laws of human nature.

Comment: Personally, I feel that it's very much a social psychology question - is there a general human tendency to act like this is really the question here. It's that "nature" part of the nature vs nurture argument. Since it's asking for more the science part than the social part, I don't think a tag would be needed.

Comment: I'm wondering if such a question would be on-topic at [cogsci.se]...

Comment: I would not add a regional tag unless you add specific (as far as you know) cultural information to your question.

Comment: @user3169 For what it's worth, cultural information, and any other relevant information to the question is *required* in the question - the tag is added too.

Comment: @Zizouz212 In the question certainly if it is relevant. Specific tags should be reserved for topics that because of narrow context would only be of interest to a specific culture or region. This is because some users will filter questions by tag to focus on what they are interested in.